# AWS Visual Studio Toolkit - How do I fix: "Unhandled exception. Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException: Child process exited unexpectedly!" error?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-ec2

I have a Blazor project running in .NET Core 6 and I am trying to use the preview feature to upload my blazor project to the Amazon ECS using Fargate.

My project runs fine, but I get this error and there is nothing I can find on it:

```
Initiating deployment: ASP.NET Core App to Amazon ECS using Fargate
Configuring AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)...
Generating AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) deployment project
Saving AWS CDK deployment project to: C:\Users\McPkM\.aws-dotnet-deploy\Projects\dg3evyzs
CDK version 1.128.0 found in global node_modules.
Deploying AWS CDK project
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://152939591676/eu-west-2...
 ✅  Environment aws://152939591676/eu-west-2 bootstrapped (no changes).


Unhandled exception. Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiException: Child process exited unexpectedly!
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Runtime.ReadResponse()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.ReceiveResponse[TResponse]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Hello()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.BuildServiceProvider(ILoggerFactory loggerFactoryOverride)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.get_ServiceProvider()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Constructs.Construct..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.Construct..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.Stage..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.App..ctor(IAppProps props)
   at Minebuilds.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\McPkM\.aws-dotnet-deploy\Projects\dg3evyzs\Program.cs:line 17

<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in GC during deserialization
#

Subprocess exited with error 3762504530


Minebuilds could not be published as ASP.NET Core App to Amazon ECS using Fargate: We had an issue deploying your application to AWS. Check the deployment output for more details.
```

I cannot find more deployment output..

Comment: @OP  did you get anywhere with this?  Just started with AWS and encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with the Java AWS CDK although my output was slightly different.

Updating both npm and node js to the latest versions fixed the issue for me.